# Winsock simple Client Server, receive fails

Tags: c++, windows, networking, winsock

I am trying to run this simple server client program's using winsock. Server is accepting the clients connection, but is unable to receive the data client sends. I am struggling to find the problem.

SERVER :

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

#include<iostream>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_PORT 18000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s, new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    char *message, client_msg[2000];
    int port, c, recv_size;

    if (argc > 2)
    {
        std::cout << "usage : " << argv[1] << " <PORT>\n";
        std::cout << "If no port is given then default port is used.\n";
        std::cout << "DEFAULT PORT : 18000\n";
        return 1;
    }
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        port = atoi(argv[2]);
    }
    else
    {
        port = DEFAULT_PORT;
    }

    std::cout << "Initializing Winsock...";
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed. Error code" << WSAGetLastError();
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Initialized.\n\n";

    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not create Socket : " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Socket Created.\n";

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Bind failed with error code : " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Bind done.\n";


    listen(s, 3);

    std::cout << "Waiting for incoming connections...\n";

    while (true)
    {
        c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        new_socket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &c);
        if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            closesocket(new_socket);
            std::cout << "Accept failed with error code : " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Connection accepted.\n";

            if ((recv_size = recv(s, client_msg, 200, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                closesocket(new_socket);
                std::cout << "Receive Failed.\n\n";
            }
            else
            {
                if (strcmp(client_msg, "PASSWD"))
                {
                    message = "HELLO!";
                    send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    message = "Authentication failed!";
                    send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
                    closesocket(new_socket);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();


    return 0;
}
```

CLIENT:

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

#include<iostream>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_SERVER "127.0.0.1"
#define DEFAULT_PORT 18000
#define PASSWORD "PASSWD"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char *message, server_reply[2000], *server_addr;
    int recv_size, port = DEFAULT_PORT;

    if (argc > 4)
    {
        std::cout << "usage : " << argv[0] << " <Server IP> <Server Port> [DATA]\n\n";
        std::cout << "If any argument is missing, default values will be used.\n";
        std::cout << "Default Address : localhost (127.0.0.1)\nDefault Port : 18000\nDefault DATA: 'PASSWD'\n\n";
        return 1;
    }
    else if (argc == 4)
    {
        server_addr = argv[1];
        port = atoi(argv[2]);
        message = argv[3];
    }
    else if (argc == 3)
    {
        server_addr = argv[1];
        port = atoi(argv[2]);
        message = PASSWORD;
    }
    else if (argc == 2)
    {
        server_addr = argv[1];
        port = DEFAULT_PORT;
        message = PASSWORD;
    }
    else
    {
        server_addr = DEFAULT_SERVER;
        port = DEFAULT_PORT;
        message = PASSWORD;
        //server_addr = "127.0.0.1";
        //port = 2222;
        //message = "HELLO";
    }

    std::cout << "Initialising Winsock..\n";
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed.. Error Code : " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Winsock Initialised.\n";

    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not create socket : " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Socket Created.\n";

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_addr);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not connect to " << server_addr << " on port " << port << ".\n";
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Connected to " << server_addr << " on port " << port << ".\n\n";

    if (send(s, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Sending Data failed.\n";
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Data send.\n\n";

    //Sleep(500);

    if ((recv_size = recv(s, server_reply, 20, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        std::cout << "Receive Failed.\n\n";
    }
    else
    {


        server_reply[recv_size] = '\0';

        std::cout << server_addr << " : " << server_reply << "\n";

    }
    //Sleep(5000);

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: One problem is that strcmp() expects a null-terminated string, which isn't what you've provided it with.  Apart from that, we're not going to be able to help unless you explain *exactly* what is going wrong - are you getting an error, is the recv never returning, or what?

Comment: Sorry, my code is badly formatted without many comments. I will put comments where necessary after office ends. 
Exactly what I am trying to do is: Server listens on a port, clients connect and the first message they send is a secret key in plain text. The server receives the message and keeps the connection open if key matches or else closes it. My plan is to add thread's for multiple connections later and scale this into an event dispatching system. Later add raspberry pi into the setup and make a simple from scratch IOT Hub.

Comment: I didn't ask what you're trying to do, I asked what was going wrong.  But I think Jun has found the main issue - the server is trying to read from `s` when it should be reading from `new_socket`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thank you for responding. About that strcmp(), using "PASSWD\0" will be correct?

Comment: No, constant C strings are automatically null-terminated.  But the message in the buffer isn't.  You need to make use of `recv_size`, e.g., by saying `client_msg[recv_size] = '\0';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > if ((recv_size = recv(s, client_msg, 200, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)

Change s to new_socket in your server side code.

Comment: Thanks, Its working now. I was thinking the message is getting recieved on servers specific port, so server should be listening to its own socket. I should have read more about recv.